# Solution of complex equation

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

To get the complex solutions $z=x+yi$ of $(z-i)^3=-8i$ we do the following: $$\left (x+yi-i\right )^3=-8i \Rightarrow \sqrt[3]{\left (x+yi-i\right )^3}=\sqrt[3]{8(-i)} \Rightarrow x+yi-i=2i \Rightarrow x+(y-1)i=2i $$ From that we get $x=0$ and $y-1=2 \Rightarrow y=3$.

Therefore the compelx solutions are $z=3i$ and $z=-3i$.

Is everything correct?

Comment: By the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, you should get $3$ roots instead of $1$. So the solution is incomplete.

Comment: ALSO, how could you get $z = -3\mathrm i$ as another solution? This is an equation involving a **cubic** root.

Comment: This comes down to finding the cube roots of $-8i.$  It will be easier if you start by writing $-8i=8e^{3\pi i/2}$

Comment: What is the purpose of the first paragraph?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not correct. Your solution $z=-3i$ does not satisfy your equation.

To solve the equation $$ (z-i)^3 = -8i$$
you may let $w=z-i$ and solve $w^3=-8i$ which gives you three solutions for $w$

$w=-2e^{i\pi /6}$, $w=-2e^{i\pi /6 +2 \pi i/3}$,$w=-2e^{i\pi /6 +4\pi i /3}$

Then you find $z=w+i$ for each $w$ and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Let $w=z-i$, you want to solve for $w^3=-8i$. This means
$$w^3+8i=(w)^3-(2i)^3=(w-2i)(w^2+2iw-4)=0$$
So $w=2i$ is one solution. The other two solutions are (by solving the quadratic)
$$w=-i+\sqrt{3} \text{ and } w=-i-\sqrt{3}.$$
Thus
$$z=3i, \sqrt{3}, -\sqrt{3}$$